# Trying to fill a page with pictures in a for loop

Tags: python, html, flask, layout

I have a loop that fills the page with pictures but they do so vertically.

```
    {% for i in range(amount) %}
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
       <div class="contents-block">
        <div class="image"><img src="/static/assets/img/uploaded/coro.png" />
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
   </div>
```

[image]

How do i make it so that the pictures fill the entire page in a grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images are lining up in a column because all your `<img>` tags are under a parent column. And the reason why the right side part is empty and the single image is not covering the entire width is due to the size of the image.

To answer your question on how to make an image grid covering the entire width, my idea will be to contain all the images inside a div and use `n` columns

```
<div class="images">
    {% for i in range(amount) %}
        <img src="/static/assets/img/uploaded/coro.png" />
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

and the CSS will be

```
.images {
  /* Prevent vertical gaps */
  line-height: 0;
  column-count: 5; /* this depends on size, no.of images and viewport(for making it responsive) */
  column-gap: 0px;  
}

.images img {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it still only lines up in a single column

Comment: Sorry the for loop was supposed to be inside, I edited the answer, check it out